# Why can I use the US Ascii Locale to upper/lowercase german Umlauts?

Tags: java, ascii, locale

suggest the following code:

```
package org.apache.creadur.rat2.core.ds;

import java.util.Locale;

public class TestUsAsciiLocale {
    public static void main(String[] pArgs) throws Exception {
        final String capitalLetterAe = "\u00c4";
        final String smallLetterAe = "\u00e4";
        if (capitalLetterAe.toLowerCase(Locale.GERMANY).equals(smallLetterAe)) {
            System.out.println("Capital Ae, and small ae are the same (case insensitive) in the german Locale.");
        }
        if (capitalLetterAe.toLowerCase(Locale.US).equals(smallLetterAe)) {
            System.out.println("Capital Ae, and small ae are the same (case insensitive) in the US Locale.");
        }
    }
}
```

Output is follows:

```
Capital Ae, and small ae are the same (case insensitive) in the german Locale.
Capital Ae, and small ae are the same (case insensitive) in the US Locale.
```

I find this surprising. I'd expect the US Ascii Locale to treat exactly [a-zA-Z]
as upper/lowercaseable.

Thanks,

Jochen

Comment: You're using Germany twice in your example code.

Comment: What is "the US Ascii Locale"?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Aren't there some states where they only speak 7-bit ASCII?

Comment: @Kayaman ...over 300 baud modems using acoustic couplers. :-)

Comment: Sorry for the initial error. The second use of Locale.GERMANY ought to be Locale.US. The example is now fixed, the output (and the question) remain the same.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in your code:

```
    if (capitalLetterAe.toLowerCase(Locale.GERMANY).equals(smallLetterAe)) {
        System.out.println("Capital Ae, and small ae are the " +
             "same (case insensitive) in the US Locale.");
    }
```

You are using `Locale.GERMANY` but the message says "in the US Locale".

Answer (score 1):

The javadoc of the `toLowerCase(Locale)` is pretty clear about it:

> Converts all of the characters in this String to lower case using the rules of the given Locale. Case mapping is based on the Unicode Standard version specified by the Character class. Since case mappings are not always 1:1 char mappings, the resulting String may be a different length than the original String.

This means the Locale parameter is used to retrieve translation rules. Maybe you confused it with a Charset, which is something different.

Answer (score 1):

Unicode has a default [case mapping](http://unicode.org/faq/casemap_charprop.html). Java's [String.toLowerCase(Locale)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase-java.util.Locale-) uses the default where there is no "tailoring" data provided for the specified Locale's case mapping of the string. It would be more astonishing if letters had a case change in every locale where they are used but not in locales where they are not used.

BTW—English uses more Unicode letters than A-Z and a-z, anyway. You've got my antennæ up on this one.

Comment: Hi, Tom, could you please elaborate on that other letters beyond [a-zA-Z]?

Comment: Notice that I said Unicode letters, by which I mean codepoints in the various Unicode letter categories. There are [ligatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_words_that_may_be_spelled_with_a_ligature) and [diacritcs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_terms_with_diacritical_marks) (probably the most common word is résumé), and maybe some words with ñ in English dictionaries.